# How to plot a function with the pandas library using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Please, I need some help, so I am still in the learning phase of the Python programming for Data Science. I tried plotting a function but I am getting this. Please, what can I do? I am using Python 3. I appreciate your insights, explanations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import rcParams
import seaborn as sb

mtcars = pd.read_csv('mtcars.csv')
mtcars.columns = ['Car names','mpg','cyl','disp','hp','drat','wt','qsec','vs','am','gear','carb']
mpg1 = mtcars['mpg']
print(mpg1.plot())

df = mtcars[['mpg','cyl','wt']]
print(df.plot())
```

When I run to see what the plot is like, this is what I get:

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)

Please can you explain? How can I see the plot?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't "print" the plot, instead you should just call `mpg1.plot()` (eventually follpwed by `plt.show()` if needed)